# Is it okay to reference a binary assembly instead of a DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, reference

I've inherited a legacy application with two solutions. The one solution is a windows forms(UI) application and the other is a windows service.

The windows service solution references the User Interface exe, this is the implementation that I found already existing in the application.

When running the windows service however I receive the following error:

> ...posting service main loop failed Could not load file or assembly
>   'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=abcc533bcb766348' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format

I was initially tasked with upgrading this solution from .Net version 3.5 to .Net version 4.5, which I did successfully, yet this reference is causing me issues.

Can someone educate me on the effects of referencing an .exe binary from C#. I cannot change the solution being referenced to a class library as it has a User Interface built using the .Net C# Windows Forms tools, so it's output type is 'Windows Application'

Any and all assistance is tremendously appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you extract code that is being used in service from Winforms application into Class library? Then make reference to that class lib from both winforms and service projects

Answer (score 2):

Referencing an EXE assembly or an DLL assembly does not make a difference in .NET, they are both assemblies and .NET can handle them with no problem.

The problem in your case seems to be incompatibility in the platform build for and running on: 32 vs. 64 bits. It is possible that the project was built for 64 bits and you are trying to run in on a 32-bits system.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response, I will go and confirm now, but as far as I know I explicitly built everything on both solutions to run on 32bits (i.e. Platform Target = x86)

Comment: Maybe you are referencing an third-party reference with 64-bits?

Comment: After re-checking I noticed one other place where it was set to compile for "Any CPU". I am set to do the latest test shortly and then I'll get back to you. Thanks again for your help, really appreciate it.

Comment: When using any CPU, the machine executing the one assembly will execute with 64bits if capable of 64bits, yet the other application is set for explicit 32bits, which might be causing the issue. But it's definitely not a third party assembly causing it because all of the dll's are in house except for the core .Net ones.

Comment: But the process will determine which platform to use, and all AnyCPU assemblies can adapt themselves to comply with both x86 and x86-64.